# Unable to load CCNEP in z/OS 1.12 C++ compiler error?

Tags: c++, mainframe

I've just got started on mainframe for couple days. I tried to compile/link/run a simple "Hello World" example follow the tutorial from this site http://www.ibmpressbooks.com/articles/article.asp?p=1160471&seqNum=4
Unfortunately, I encountered this error and I have no idea what it is telling me. I wonder if anyone have experiences in mainframe could share me some tips? I'm running Marist z/OS 1.12.
[image]

Comment: FYI, and unrelated to your problem, but never call a program `test`. In many systems there are built-in commands named `test` that may collide with your program.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Thanks for the advice. I was a little sloppy on that.

Answer (score 2):

The [IBM C/C++ compiler](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=zos-xl-cc) is documented in the IBM Documentation for your particular release of z/OS.

The compiler messages are documented [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=cc-zos-xl-messages), and indicate that CCNEP is the name of a module required by the compiler which could not be loaded.

> User response: Check that the compiler is installed correctly. Make
> sure there is enough memory in the region to fetch the module. You may
> need to specify the runtime option HEAP(,,,FREE,,) to prevent the
> compiler from running out of memory.

Since you are compiling in the foreground, and I see you are using OMVS, the amount of memory "in the region" is that specified for your TSO session.

The runtime option mentioned is a [Language Environment](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=environment-zos-language-concepts-guide) runtime option.  Language Environment provides a [common runtime environment](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=zlecg-overview) used by C/C++, COBOL, FORTRAN, and PL/I.

There are a number of ways to [specify runtime options](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=options-how-specify-runtime), my guess is you would prefer using the _CEE_RUNOPTS environment variable.

It is also possible that the library containing the CCNEP module isn't allocated to your session, and/or is unavailable in LPA or the linklist.

Depending on your background, you might be more comfortable using PuTTY than OMVS.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried `_CEE_RUNOPTS="HEAP(,,,FREE,,)", but still had the same error. Any other idea?

Comment: The exercise you're doing states "The size field in the TSO logon screen specifies the region size, the maximum amount of memory that will be allocated to you for that TSO logon. The C compiler requires a lot of memory, so you might need to increase this number from the default to about 2MB."  You might want to try increasing your region size on the TSO logon screen if you can.  I would suggest at least 8MB if possible.

Comment: Increasing the size of `REGION` to `250M` still doesn't help. Anyway, thanks. I guess Marist College probably does not provide CCNEP module.

Comment: Another possibility is that the library that contains CCNEP is not immediately accessible to your TSO session. There are ways to create an access path to it, but it is rather complex to set up what is necessary under TSO. To continue with what cschneid suggested, does Marist provide standard telnet access directly into OMVS/USS? If so, it is easier to specify the access path to the required data set to load CCNEP under a direct USS connection. Please let us know. (Common port numbers for telnet access are 23, 623, or 1023, whichever are not being used for TN3270.)

Comment: @zarchasmpgmr: I'm not quite sure if Marist provide standard telnet directly into OMVS since I ran it via TSO. During this Winter break, it's very difficult to contact administration people at Marist. By the way, I used port 1023 to connect to their site. A reference to set up access path would be extremely helpful for me. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: I would try pointing a telnet client to port 23. You should be able to log in with your TSO userid. Also, there is a way to specify a STEPLIB via an environment variable. I will have to look up the specific variable when I get back to work on Wednesday.

Answer (score 0):

I expect this isn't a memory issue but instead that the C/C++ compiler modules aren't in your STEPLIB.
The STEPLIB is (one of) the places that load modules are looked for - similar to LIBPATH on Unix systems.
So - what you want to do is add an export command before running c++. This really is something the systems programmer should have probably set up for you, but often they don't. 
Unfortunately, it isn't standardized - but for me - the CCNEP program object is in CBC.ACCNCMP dataset, so I would do the following:

```
(export STEPLIB=CBC.ACCNCMP:$STEPLIB; c++ ... )
```

That will run (as a child process so you don't muck up your global STEPLIB) the C++ compiler, but first add the dataset CBC.ACCNCMP to your STEPLIB, so that the c++ driver program can load the module CCNEP.

If you know the systems programmer for Marist, they should be able to tell you where they installed the C++ compiler.